# NSJSONSerialization returning null - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to test a NSJSONSerialization with this URL ; the link works, and the app runs, but when I log the serialization, I get a null result.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- ( void )viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:franciscocosta.net/lisbon-spots"]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[self getURLSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^( NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error )
    {dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
^{
NSError *jsonError;
NSArray *parsedJSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

    NSLog( @"%@", parsedJSONArray );
                        } );
                    }];
    [task resume];
}

- ( NSURLSession * )getURLSession
{
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once( &onceToken,
                  ^{
                      NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                      session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
                  } );

    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your JSON is not well-formed.

If type your link into Safari, then copy the resulting JSON and paste it into a JSON verifier like JSONLint, it shows an error on line 25. It looks like there is closing bracket (`]`) that doesn't belong there. It appears that that JSON contains 2 root array objects, which I don't think is valid.

If you refactor it to contain a single array of dictionaries, it passes the JSONLint test as valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Duncan, I did the same, and yes, there's an error with the JSON